# Slick Slider: Highlighting text links when on the corresponding slide

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to create a carousel with some custom navigation. I've got a set of text links that when clicked will make the slider slide to the corresponding slide. That works great.

I want to make also the reverse happen though, so when the user uses the arrows on the slider to navigate through it will highlight the corresponding text link. How can I do that? Is there a way to use active `data-slide` of the slider to highlight the corresponding link?

Here's my code so far:

Jquery:

```
$('.category-gallery').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    centerMode:true,
    arrows: true,
});

$('a.category-nav[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
    $('.category-gallery').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
});
```

This creates the set of links for the navigation:

```
<div class="category-links">
  <?php $counter = 1; ?>
  <section class="row category-term-list" data-equalizer>
  <?php foreach ( $pages as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="columns medium-2 text-center" data-equalizer-watch>
      <a class="category-nav" data-slide="<?php echo $counter; ?>" href="#"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
  <?php $counter++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </section>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

This creates the carousel:

```
  <?php if( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ): the_row(); ?>
                <?php $image = get_sub_field( 'image' );
      $icon = get_field( 'product_icon' ); ?>
                <a href="#" class="slide" data-open="gallery-modal-<?php echo $counter; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php if($icon) { ?><img src="<?php echo $icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $icon['alt']; ?>"><?php } ?>
                </a>
            <?php break;
    endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

---

This is my attempt:

```
$('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

It's not quite right as it's adding an active class to every link when you scroll through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working with the following:

```
$('a.category-nav[data-slide="1"]').addClass("highlighted-cat-nav");
$('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $('a.category-nav').removeClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
  $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this event handler to your code, it will return the current slide's ID.

```
$('.category-gallery').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $("#text-link-number-" + currentSlide).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly, I've added that code block under my jquery but nothing seems to happen. Is that trying to add an active class to the slide?

Comment: This adds a class (active, that you've already mentioned it in your css) to your text link <a>

Comment: I've updated my question with the amended code, added that underneath my original block of jquery and it doesn't seem to mark anything as active.